# Sustainsys.Saml2 -MVC Error "The signature verified correctly with the key contained in the signature, but that key is not trusted""

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, saml-2.0

I have a Web MVC 4 Web application based on .net framework 4.8 that is using nuget "Sustainsys.Saml2" versión 1.0.0.

After the user has logged in into the IDP login page and has been redirected to the Web Aplication
i got the error "Sustainsys.Saml2.Exceptions.InvalidSignatureException:
The signature verified correctly with the key contained in the signature,
but that key is not trusted";

The following image is from the SAMl2.config file used

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPbFU.png)

There is a .cer certicate that was used was created based on the .xml metadata found in the section "X509Certificate" where it is shown as base 64 encoded text;

I thought is was becouse the .cer certificate was not trusted by the Application Server, so i installed on "local Computer" as "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgWKu.png)

Any ideas about how to solve the error thrown ?

Thanks in advance